# Stacked Visualization using Ratios - Power BI

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to figure out the best way to visualize Active Session History data from Oracle/Postgres without reinventing the wheel.  I can collect and model the data just fine, but I'm really struggling to find a visualization that will do anything even remotely close to what this is doing

[image: ASH Viewer Sample]

It's an area map with time on the x and count of active sessions on the y, but I can't seem to find a visualization in Power BI capable of mapping all of the different combinations shown, and admittedly and very much still getting my feet wet in analytics and the like.

A couple of examples of what I'm doing with the data model.  The core model is:
[image: Data Model Example 1 of 2]

I've also tried creating sub tables, if you will, of each Wait Type you see color coded below.  I know I'm missing something and have probably gotten myself into the weeds, please help me back my way out :)

Questions are:

1. Does anyone know if there's a viz capable of this in Power BI
2. Am I way out of bounds for what I'm trying to do in Power BI?
3. Any thoughts on what the heck I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much!

Edit:  Adding this for Area Stacked Chart.  This works great if I'm looking at larger grades of data, like over days, weeks or months.  In this case, I'm trying to get a reasonable picture by minute, which ends up looking pretty messy overall.  I believe this is because its just plotting my x/y axis data points and isn't actually taking the ratio of waits into account.  [image: Area Stacked Chart]

Link to example pbix:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=16wGvKcbSHXMBNbAhTZQHdgmua0KEWVTB

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in stacked area chart visual. Broadly speaking, you'd put time on the x-axis and your categorization on in the Legend box which would split out the measure you put into the Value box into different pieces similar to your chart.

Here's an example from [Tutorial Gateway](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/stacked-area-chart-in-power-bi/):

[image: Stacked Area Chart Example]

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Unfortunately the Area Stacked chart gets REAL messy when trying to use samples that occur every minute.  I edited my original post to include a screenshot of what that looks like.

Comment: Ah, I see. Any chance you can share a sample PBIX so I can try a couple of workarounds?

Comment: Super nice of you to take a look - pbix is attached.  Thank you!

Comment: well, its linked...not attached :)

Comment: I've taken a look. The main issue here is that the data is sparse and it isn't clear how to turn that into a continuous sort of chart. If nothing was logged during a particular second (or minute), what should the chart value show for that time?

Comment: That makes sense.  I have to model the entire series, the Visual isn't going to plug in gaps for me.  Let me think that through - that makes a lot more sense

Comment: I think the big thing in the visual I'm trying to recreate, is that its not just a stacked chart:  its a stacked chart based on ratio of wait class over time.  So, for example, Dark Blue represents User IO in the screenshot I provided, and its slice/coloring is proportionate to the percentage of its overall place within the waits for that time.  Green is for CPU, so we can see that we're largely waiting on CPU most of the time - hope that makes sense.  I don't see anything in Power BI that could provide that - its almost likes its two visuals in Power BI